# Killing App, in onTrimMemory method in Application class

Tags: java, android, performance

I want to kill my app when it is going into background from foreground. 
I have implemented onTrimMemory method in Application class, this method is successfully called. I tried System.exit(0) but it restarts app rather than killing it from background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `System.exit(0);`, try using

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

It essentially does the same thing but is the more "Android" way of doing things.

EDIT: Per request of your comment, add these two lines to you AndroidManifest file:

```
android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
android:noHistory="true"
```

Put them in your main `<activity>`. Then, when the user leaves the app, it will not be in the history/recents.

Comment: It still showing me app in recents. I want to kill app when user press home button?

Comment: Ah I see. I have a method for that too, let me find it and I will update my answer.

Comment: did you find it?

Comment: Has this worked for you? If it has, please mark this as the correct answer. If not, let me know and I can help you further.

Comment: As per your answer I have to add these flags in all activities. Because user can press Home Button from any opened activity. So What is suitable. Because I want to kill it in application file. If possible

Comment: If you want it to work in every activity then yes, you will have to add it to each activity in the Manifest file. EDIT: The reason is because the `<application>` part of the Manifest does not allow these flags

Answer (score 1):

When I need to shut down the app I use this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
```

> Terminates the currently running Java virtual machine by initiating its shutdown sequence. This method never returns normally. The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit(int)